# Spring Security custom RememberMeAuthenticationFilter not getting fired

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have implemented 'Remember Me' functionality in my Spring MVC application using Spring Security 3.1

My security-context.xml looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <import resource="servlet-context.xml" />
    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

    <security:http auto-config="true" authentication-manager-ref="am">

    <!-- Restrict URLs based on role -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/public/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

    <!-- Override default login and logout pages -->
    <security:form-login login-page="/public/login" 
                 login-processing-url="/public/loginProcess" 
                 default-target-url="/public/loginSuccess" 
                 authentication-failure-url="/public/login?login_error=1" 
                 always-use-default-target="true" />
    <security:logout logout-url="/public/logout" logout-success-url="/public/login?logout=1" />
    <security:remember-me services-alias="rmService" data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
    <security:custom-filter position="LAST" ref="httpResponseAuthFilter" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager id="am">
    <security:authentication-provider >
        <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="httpResponseAuthFilter"
    class="mypackage.HttpResponseAuthenticationFilter" >
     <property name="authenticationManager" ref="am"/>
     <property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rmService"></property>
    </bean> 

</beans>
```

The Filter class is implemented like this :

```
    public class HttpResponseAuthenticationFilter extends RememberMeAuthenticationFilter {

    @Override
    protected void onSuccessfulAuthentication(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
            final Authentication authResult) {

        super.onSuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, authResult);

        if (authResult != null) {
            // process post authentication logic here..
        }
    }

}
```

Remember me functionality works fine using the above configuration but while running in eclipse debugger I found that HttpResponseAuthenticationFilter.onSuccessfulAuthentication() doesn't get invoked.

**EDIT**

After modifying my security-context.xmls and defining the remember-me service using standard Spring beans and referencing the service inside  the configuration looks

```
    <security:http auto-config="true" authentication-manager-ref="am">
    <!-- Restrict URLs based on role -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/public/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

    <!-- Override default login and logout pages -->
    <security:form-login login-page="/public/login" 
                         login-processing-url="/public/loginProcess" 
                         default-target-url="/public/loginSuccess" 
                         authentication-failure-url="/public/login?login_error=1" 
                         always-use-default-target="true" />

    <security:remember-me services-ref="rememberMeService"/>
    <security:logout logout-url="/public/logout" logout-success-url="/public/login?logout=1" />
    <security:custom-filter position="LAST" ref="httpResponseAuthFilter" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager id="am">
    <security:authentication-provider >
        <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" class=
        "org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="key" value="riskAnalysis" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="httpResponseAuthFilter"
    class="mypacakge.HttpResponseAuthenticationFilter" >
     <property name="authenticationManager" ref="am"/>
     <property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeService"></property>
</bean> 

<bean id="rememberMeService"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
    <property name="key" value="riskAnalysis" />
</bean>

<bean id="userDetailsService"
  class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Here is what I get in the logs :

*DEBUG: mypackage.HttpResponseAuthenticationFilter - SecurityContextHolder not populated with remember-me token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationToken@303f2184: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@cb7ea6f6: Username: tarun4; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER'*

So it looks like authentication information is present in the session.

Thanks,
Tarun

Answer (score 2):

The `remember-me` namespace element already inserts a `RememberMeAuthenticationFilter` so it will still take precedence over yours, since it comes before it in the filter chain.

If you want to use a custom filter, you should remove the namespace element and use standard Spring beans for the related services. There's an example [in the reference manual (Section 11.4.1)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#remember-me-impls) which shows the beans needed.

Comment: Could you please review the changes I made to see if it looks fine now. After making the above changes I see debug logs from the Filter class that I added : 'DEBUG: mypackage.HttpResponseAuthenticationFilter - SecurityContextHolder not populated with remember-me token'
But I haven't been able to see the control reaching my onSuccessfulAuthentication method.

Comment: Also probably its worth mentioning here that in the [in the reference manual (Section 11.4.1)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#remember-me-impls) the package name for RememberMeAuthenticationProvider is mentioned incorrectly as org.springframework.security.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider,  the correct package name is org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider

Comment: Please add the full log message to your question. Either the token was rejected or the security context already contains an `Authentication` object (take a look at [the code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java#L142)).